# Change the end of multiple similar filenames

Tags: bash, text-processing, files, rename, filenames

I have many files that look similar to this:

```
56.mp3?referredby=rss
```

What I want to do is remove the `?referredby=rss` so they'll be like this:

```
56.mp3
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Perl `rename`, it’s as easy as

```
rename 's/\?referredby=rss//' ./*referredby=rss
```

With `util-linux` `rename`:

```
rename '?referredby=rss' '' ./*referredby=rss
```

Comment: Why do you have to put the `./` in the second part of the first command?

Comment: That avoids issues with files whose names start with `-` (they would end being interpreted as options rather than files).

Answer (score 2):

Aside from escaping the `?` (which has special meaning in glob expressions) this is really no different from renaming any other files: so for example you could use a simple shell loop

```
for f in *.mp3\?referredby=rss; do mv -- "$f" "${f%\?*}"; done
```

where `${f%\?*}` is a shell parameter expansion that removes the shortest trailing element matching `\?*`